# Express regular expression matching

Tags: regex, node.js, express

`app.get('/api/transactions/:hash([0-9a-fA-F]{64})', transaction.get);`

I want anything that goes to `/api/transactions/SOMEHASH` to be picked up by that route. All hashes will be 64 characters and be hex. However, this doesn't seem to work. Ideas?

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Throws an error? Runs the wrong route? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.param('hash', /^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$/);
app.get('/api/transactions/:hash', transaction.get);
```